# Ionic iOS app can't receive FCM push notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

I’m having a problem with notifications from an app in Ionic 4.11.7.

I have followed the official Firebase guide for configuration, configured APN keys, added GoogleService-Info.plist file to my project path. I use postman to launch the notifications but they do not appear in the app and there is no error in postman either, the result is successful, I’ll leave here my Ionic info and the request I do on postman. The same request is working on Android without any problem. I don't know what more can I do, if anyone has a suggestion please share it here.

The plugin I’m using is “cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated”: “^4.1.1”, and “@ionic-native/fcm”: “^5.19.1”,

```
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
```

Postman request

```
{ 
    "to" : "csws...D-11",
    "notification": {
        "body": "Test message",
        "title": "Title"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this? We're experiencing a similar issue intermittently.